# Replace letras segun distancia

Tags: java

Necesito realizar método de codificación donde cada letra se sustituye por otra letra que se encuentra a una distancia N posiciones hacia adelante en el alfabeto.

El texto tiene que convertir mayúsculas a minúsculas si las hay.

El alfabeto es circular, es decir, la letra después de la "z" vuelve a ser la "a".

Ej:

```
code("a", 1) → return "b"
code("a", 3) → return "c"
code("z", 2) → return "b"
code("vaca", 5) → return "afhf"
code("vaca", 31) → return "afhf"
code("vaca", 26) → return "vaca"
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo pero no acaba de funcionar como me gustaria:

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public String code(String text, int distance) {
    // cambio mayus <-> minus
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

    for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
        char c = sb.charAt(index);

        if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
        } else {
            sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }

    // comparison string to ALPHABET
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0, j < ALPHABET.length(); j++) {
            //tiene en cuenta mayusculas y minusculas
            if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] && sb[i] == ALPHABET[j].toUpperCase()) {
                // adds the distance
                sb[i] = ALPHABET[j+distance];
            }
        }
    }

    return sb;
}
```

El resultado me da el siguient error:

```
error: array required, but StringBuilder found
                    if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] || sb[i] == ALPHABET[j].toUpperCase()) {
```

Comment: "pero no acaba de funcionar como me gustaria";

Podrías elaborar un poco en este punto? Hay algun error o alguna parte del código que quisieras mejorar?

Comment: me da el siguient error: error: array required, but StringBuilder found
                    if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] || sb[i] == ALPHABET[j].toUpperCase()) {

Comment: Lo que tampoco se es si el resto del codigo esta bien para llegar al resultado final.

Comment: Porfavor añade esos detalles a la pregunta; esto facilitara contestarte la pregunta a otras personas que esten en el sitio. ( https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: Podrías encontrar más información si lo buscas como cifrado de César

Answer (score 2):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0, j < ALPHABET.length(); j++) {
            //tiene en cuenta mayusculas y minusculas
            if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] && sb[i] == ALPHABET[j].toUpperCase()) {
                // adds the distance
                sb[i] = ALPHABET[j+distance];
            }
        }
    }
```

Este bucle esta mal por dos motivos:

- En el segundo for pones una coma para separar la inicialización de la condición de salida ( un missclick ), debería ser ;
- La condición del if nunca se cumplirá, pues ningún carácter será igual a una letra y su mayúscula a la vez.

Sugerencia de arreglos:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET.length(); j++) {
            //tiene en cuenta mayusculas y minusculas
            if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] ) {
                // adds the distance
                sb[i] = ALPHABET[j+distance];
            }
            if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j].toUpperCase() ) {
                // adds the distance
                sb[i] = ALPHABET[j+distance].toUpperCase();
            }
        }
    }
```

Es un arreglo para la solución que propones, aunque se me ocurren soluciones mejores utilizando conjuntos, transformaciones a ASCII, etc ...

Un saludo !

Edito:
Corrijo tipo y añado alfabeto circular

```
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHABET.length(); j++) {
            //tiene en cuenta mayusculas y minusculas
            index= j+distance;
            if(index>26)
                index-=26;
            if (sb.charAt(i)==ALPHABET.charAt(j))  {
                // adds the distance
                sb.setCharAt(i, ALPHABET.charAt(j+distance));
            }
            if (sb.charAt(i)==Character.toUpperCase(ALPHABET.charAt(j)))  {
                // adds the distance
                sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(ALPHABET.charAt(j+distance)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Me salta el mismo error con tu codigo: error: array required, but StringBuilder found
                if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] ) {

Comment: Es tema de tipos. Tambien te falta lo del alfabeto circular. De todas formas esta mucho mejor la solucion de @dramaturgo

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero usar la codificación ASCII para realizar ese tipo de cifrado,con ello no solo podras transformar palabra sino frases obviando los espacios

```
public class cifrado {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(code("a",3));
       System.out.println(code("z",2));
       System.out.println(code("vaca",5));
       System.out.println(code("vaca",31));
       System.out.println(code("vaca",26));

}
    public static String code(String cadenaOriginal, int rotaciones) {
        // En ASCII, la a es 97, b 98, A 65, B 66, etcétera
        final int LONGITUD_ALFABETO = 26, INICIO_MINUSCULAS = 97, INICIO_MAYUSCULAS = 65;
        String cadenaRotada = ""; // La cadena nueva, la que estará rotada
        for (int x = 0; x < cadenaOriginal.length(); x++) {
            char caracterActual = cadenaOriginal.charAt(x);
            // Si no es una letra del alfabeto entonces ponemos el char tal y como está
            // y pasamos a la siguiente iteración
            if (!Character.isLetter(caracterActual)) {
                cadenaRotada += caracterActual;
                continue;
            }

            int codigoAsciiDeCaracterActual = (int) caracterActual;
            boolean esMayuscula = Character.isUpperCase(caracterActual);

            // La posición (1 a 26) que ocupará la letra después de ser rotada
            // El % LONGITUD_ALFABETO se utiliza por si se pasa de 26. Por ejemplo,
            // la "z", al ser rotada una vez da el valor de 27, pero en realidad debería
            // regresar a la letra "a", y con mod hacemos eso ya que 27 % 26 == 1,
            // 28 % 26 == 2, etcétera ;)
            int nuevaPosicionEnAlfabeto = ((codigoAsciiDeCaracterActual
                    - (esMayuscula ? INICIO_MAYUSCULAS : INICIO_MINUSCULAS)) + rotaciones) % LONGITUD_ALFABETO;
            // Arreglar rotaciones negativas
            if (nuevaPosicionEnAlfabeto < 0)
                nuevaPosicionEnAlfabeto += LONGITUD_ALFABETO;
            int nuevaPosicionAscii = (esMayuscula ? INICIO_MAYUSCULAS : INICIO_MINUSCULAS) + nuevaPosicionEnAlfabeto;
            // Convertir el código ASCII numérico a su representación como símbolo o letra y
            // concatenar
            cadenaRotada += Character.toString((char) nuevaPosicionAscii);
        }
        return cadenaRotada;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]