# Codificando un string

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java. Estoy intentando implementar un método que permita codificar una cadena de texto recibida como parámetro `text`. El texto de entrada únicamente tiene carácteres de la a-z y signos de puntuación. La codificación tiene que ser la siguiente:

1. El texto puede tener letras en mayúsculas pero estas se tienen que convertir a minúsculas.
2. Los signos de puntuación se ignoran.
3. Cada letra del texto se substituye por otra que se encuentra a una distancia **N posiciones adelante en el alfabeto**. Este valor N viene determinado por el parámetro `distance`.
4. El alfabeto es circular, es decir, la siguiente letra después de la 'z' es la 'a'.
5. El parámetro distance puede tener una longitud mayor a la del alfabeto (26). Al ser circular, si es mayor que 26, volverá al inicio.

Hasta el momento he hecho lo siguiente:

```
public class Codificando {

      private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

      /*
      ** @param text: texto que tendrá que ser codificado 
      ** @param distance: valor de desplazamiento en el alfabeto
      */
      public String code (String text, int distance){
           // Convertimos el texto de entrada a minúsculas
           String text_low = text.toLowerCase();
           // Separamos el texto en letras
           String[] text_letters = text_low.split("");
           // Problemática a resolver


}}
```

Mi idea es separar el texto recibido en letras e ir a buscar estas letras en la constante `ALPHABET` y aplicar el desplazamiento pero no consigo saber cómo hacerlo.

Unos ejemplos de aplicación y resultado del método seria:

```
code("a",1) -> return "b"
code("a",3) -> return "c"
code("z",2) -> return "b"
code("vaca",5) -> return "afhf"
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: esta pregunta ya se habia realizado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/491849/replace-letras-segun-distancia

Comment: Muchas gracias!